# How to control whether to show process instance variables in Camunda Tasklist?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I try to run an [example](https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/master/showcases/bank-account-opening-error-handling/src/main/resources/open-account-errorhandling.bpmn) provided from the official net.
There are two usertasks set as this:
[image]
[image]

But in the UserTask app, I can see variables in one usertask and can't in the other, I want to know why and how to control this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? The tasklist screenshots displaying in both tasks the variables. Be aware that approved is an boolean variable so there is only a checkbox.

Comment: In check document(the last picture), I can't find variables: firstname, lastname, accounttype.But in the manual processing I can see them all.